# TikZ change reference point

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ, picture is drew based on the point (0,0). if my whole picture is based on the point, e.g., (20,0)? how can i draw it easily? it is better to transform the reference point from (0,0) to (20.0). i tried this:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[shift={(20mm,0)}]
```

but it didn't work. `shift` works for many commands, but it seems that it doesn't work for environment. it is not good to add `shift` option to every command.

@Martin: adding `shift` with `scope` seemed to have no influence on the whole picture. i want the two grids to move to the right. for the whole picture, there will have many other items. to construct the picture easily, it is better to refer to the point (0,0). but for the whole picture display, it is better to put it based on the point (20,0)

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.500000cm,rmargin=2.500000cm,tmargin=2.500000cm,bmargin=2.500000cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section[General remarks]{General remarks}
\subsection[Geometry and coordinate system]{Geometry and coordinate system}
The main layout of the structure is adopted:\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,thick]
  \begin{scope}[shift={(20mm,0)}]
    \foreach \xoffset in {0,5.2}
    {
      \begin{scope}[shift={(\xoffset,0)}]
      \draw[xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (5,5);
      \end{scope}
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shifting the whole picture doesn't make much sense.
TikZ cuts every picture to its minimal bounding box.
Therefore drawing from e.g. (0,0) to (10,10) or from (100,100) to (110,110) will give you the same visual result!

If you want to "move the picture 20mm to the right" you can put an otherwise empty path which includes (-20mm,0), so that the bounding box will be extended for this amount:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section[General remarks]{General remarks}
\subsection[Geometry and coordinate system]{Geometry and coordinate system}
The main layout of the structure is adopted:\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1]
    \path (-20mm,0);
    \foreach \xoffset in {0,5.2}
    {
      \begin{scope}[shift={(\xoffset,0)}]
      \draw[xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (5,5);
      \end{scope}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If this isn't what you want tell me please.

Comment: but it didn't work.

Comment: @warem: I see I misunderstood your question. However It doesn't make that much sense to shift the complete picture! Nevertheless `shift` should work. Try to place the whole picture content into a `scope` environment with the `shift` option.

Comment: it still didn't work. i added a small example in the original text. please have a look.

Answer (score 14):

The issue, I think, is to do with the *internal* and *external* specifications of the picture.  When you draw a picture using TikZ then you scribble lots of stuff all over the page, using whatever coordinates you like.  When you've finished, TikZ very nicely goes around your picture with a pair of scissors and cuts it out.  It then hands it over to the TeX page layout builder and says, "Here's your picture.".  The TeX page layout builder just gets the picture as-is and doesn't look closely at it.  Indeed, as far as the layout builder is concerned, the picture could just be a frame.  In particular, the layout builder doesn't look to see what coordinates you used in designing your picture.

So if you want your picture placed somewhere particular on the page, it's not TikZ that you need to talk to, but the layout builder.  A simple way would be to tell her to put a big blank space in front of it, aka `\hspace{2cm}` (or `\hspace*{2cm}` if the former gets ignored).

It *is* possible to do what you want from within TikZ, though, by making the picture *effectively* bigger.  Then when TikZ goes round with his scissors, he cuts the frame that he thinks is there whether or not there is actually anything in the picture (he's a bit dumb, you see).

Slightly less prosaically, in your picture then there is nothing at `(0,0)` so it gets ignored when computing the picture size.  If you put something there then it will not be ignored.  The trick is to put something there but to do it in a way that is *actually nothing*.  (It's a bit like the emptyset in mathematics: it is nothing, but the fact that it is nothing is still something.)

Here's one way:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.500000cm,rmargin=2.500000cm,tmargin=2.500000cm,bmargin=2.500000cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\section[General remarks]{General remarks}
\subsection[Geometry and coordinate system]{Geometry and coordinate system}
The main layout of the structure is adopted:\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,thick]
\path (0,0); % <--- THIS LINE IS ADDED
  \begin{scope}[shift={(20mm,0)}]
    \foreach \xoffset in {0,5.2}
    {
      \begin{scope}[shift={(\xoffset,0)}]
      \draw[xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (5,5);
      \end{scope}
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Shifted grids]

Comment: it worked. thank you for your clear concept explanation.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly tikz behaviour, the picture is actually shifted, but at the end the picture is cropped so that the only remaining parts are those that contain some drawing. To obtain what you ask, you could explicitely set a bounding box using '\useasboundingbox' command as in:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,thick]
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (70mm,5);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(20mm,0)}]
    \foreach \xoffset in {0,5.2}
    {
      \begin{scope}[shift={(\xoffset,0)}]
      \draw[xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (5,5);
      \end{scope}
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: This has the major drawback that the bounding box must be given manually in advanced. It would be better to modify the final bounding box at the very end using the special `current bounding box` node. See also my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Martin and Loop Space gave equivalent solutions. I agree with martin for LucaD's proposition, it would be better to modify the final bounding box at the very end .

Here another solution. We have only to add an option for the environment : `trim left=-20 mm`

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.500000cm,rmargin=2.500000cm,
tmargin=2.500000cm,bmargin=2.500000cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\section[General remarks]{General remarks}
\subsection[Geometry and coordinate system]{Geometry and coordinate system}
The main layout of the structure is adopted:\\

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1,trim left=-20mm]
    \foreach \xoffset in {0,5.2}
    {
      \begin{scope}[shift={(\xoffset,0)}]
      \draw[xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (5,5);
      \end{scope}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]