# Have tikz bezier control points defined off of page

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, bounding-box

I have taken it on myself to reproduce some of my university's PPT templates (not that I necessarily love the design, but I have some good reasons for undertaking this venture) using Beamer. I have taken the below image of one of the templates and, using bezier curves, converted it into Tikz code.
[image: PPT template to be mimicked]

The result looks pretty good to me, the only problem is, when defining the control points which describe the curves in the picture, some of the point lay off of the screen (i.e. they are negative values), which lowers the bottom edge of the bounding box of the Tikz image, and has the effect of "shifting up" the whole image (the largest negative value lay at the bottom edge of the page, shifting 'y=0' up by some amount). Essentially, the thing that solved [this poster's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12451/tikz-change-reference-point?rq=1) problem is what is causing mine.

Is there any way to allow either the control points to exist outside of the bounding box or let the edge of the box "slide" off the page? Or maybe some other solution that I'm not thinking of? I am fairly practiced with LaTeX in general, but not so much with Tikz or Beamer specifically. I'm not sure if the solution will be Beamer- or Tikz-specific, but this seems very much like a Tikz thing to me. If there is another way to define the curves, I would be open to learning new things, but drawing beziers with control points is so dead-simple that I would hate to leave this method.

MWE:

`beamerthemeMWE.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{mwe}

\definecolor{CincinnatiRed}{RGB}{224,1,34}

\newcommand{\footerheight}{2}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode\hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %red swoopy bit
        \path[fill=CincinnatiRed] (\paperwidth,\footerheight) .. controls %
        (0.898*\paperwidth,0.752*\footerheight) and (0.557*\paperwidth,-0.381*\footerheight) .. %
        (0,0.548*\footerheight) -- (0,0.957*\footerheight) .. controls %
        (0.529*\paperwidth,-0.169*\footerheight) and (0.882*\paperwidth,0.723*\footerheight) .. (\paperwidth,\footerheight); %
        %black swoopy bit
        \path[fill=black] (0,0) -- (\paperwidth,0) -- (\paperwidth,\footerheight) .. controls %
        (0.898*\paperwidth,0.752*\footerheight) and (0.557*\paperwidth,-0.381*\footerheight) .. %
        (0,0.548*\footerheight) -- cycle; %
        %white line
        \draw[white] (\paperwidth,\footerheight) .. controls (0.872*\paperwidth,0.647*\footerheight) and %
        (0.555*\paperwidth,-0.228*\footerheight) .. (0,0.148*\footerheight); %
        %university logo
        \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt](UC_logo) at %
        (0.966*\paperwidth,0.129*\footerheight){\includegraphics[scale=0.09] %
        {example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}
```

`mwe.tex`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme[]{MWE}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read [tikz bounding box / cropping: too much space for curves](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290357/tikz-bounding-box-cropping-too-much-space-for-curves/292373#292373)?  My answer applied to your example, does not give the right result. But it is probably adaptable.

Comment: Wow. I'm a nincompoop. `\clip` was all I needed (found from [Bounding box is larger than expected](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43621/bounding-box-is-larger-than-expected-when-drawing-a-curved-path?rq=1)). Thank you for the redirection. I guess my search-foo was definitely not up to snuff tonight.

Comment: @Paul Is this question worth keeping around? If so, a link to your other solution (which in turn linked me to a solution which worked for me) should serve as an answer which I will accept if you post it as such. Otherwise, I should delete the question, as it may not be very helpful...

Comment: I think `\useasboundingbox` is also a good approach here.

Comment: @MarkWibrow In this particular case, you are right.

Comment: @MarkWibrow Both `\clip` and `\useasboundingbox` work equally well for me with this use case. `\useasboundingbox` seems a little more elegant, so that is what I decided on.